# Is there any word or phrase meaning that internet connection is unstable?

Tags: word-choice

If you can read Chinese, what I want to ask is translate this "我的网络很卡." to English.

For example, I want to use a native expression describing a situation about downloading a file from internet, like sometimes the download speed is over 500 k/s, sometimes is less 5 k/s, it changes frequently.

Another example is that like I am playing internet game, sometimes it's fluent , sometimes the character is not moving.

I am not sure you can understand my words.

**By the way, in Chinese it is an adjective with meaning that is prone to negative.**

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a verb, it is **[fluctuate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluctuate)**.

> to change or cause to change position constantly; be or make unstable; waver or vary

Comment: Also inconsistent or even tenuous (if it is weak more often than strong) as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

The connection is *varying* or *fluctuating*. If it sometimes dies entirely, it is *intermittent*.

There's a few informal phrases that are often used.

Sometimes people use *choppy* by metaphorical reference to choppy weather at sea, that causes sharp waves. *Turbulent* by comparison to turbulence experienced in airplanes too.

*Laggy* just referring to the lag caused by the slow periods. This is not specific to a connection that's changeable, but also covers one that is always slow, though in practice it does tend to be one with slow periods; you'd have just given up trying to use it if it was always too slow.

In the context gaming, there are various joking forms of *Lag* such as *Laaa…………aag*, and references to the mysterious "Lag-monster" (who eats TCP/IP packets, hence causing the lag).

One sometimes also gets *plossy* as short for "packet loss" + an *-y* to make it an adjective, since packet loss is something that will cause poor network connections of the sort especially noticeable in gaming. This last is very much gamer-slang or hacker-slang and wouldn't be understood generally (whereas with the others, people could work out what you meant). A plossy connection is different to a slow one, as while the effect on a download is just to slow it (the lost packets get resent), in a live-action use the effect of a plossy fast connection is worse than that of a steady slow connection, resulting in the sort of freezing of your character that you describe.